# Como destruir um jobSchedule via Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-service

Estou estudando os serviços em Background do Android e consegui criar um serviço em Background que já funciona bem em background mesmo apos reiniciar o android ou fechar o App.
O problema se encontra quando eu quero encerrar o JobService por um botão na Activity.

Tentei com: `jobScheduler.cancel(id)` e `jobScheduler.cancelAll()`. Mas nenhum dos dois surtiu efeito.

Meu código esta da seguinte forma atualmente:

---

**BroadcastReceiver.java**

```java
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), ServiceLocationJob.class.getName());

                JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler) context.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);

                JobInfo jobInfo = new JobInfo.Builder(11, comp)
                        // only add if network access is required
                        .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY)
                        .setMinimumLatency(1)
                        .setOverrideDeadline(1)
                        .build();

                jobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo);
                Log.d(Tag, "Iniciado servicoJob as: " + c.getTime().toString());
            }
```

---

**ServiceLocationJob.java**

```java
    private Thread locationThread;

        @Override
        public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {

            locationThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Log.d(Tag, "Serviço (API<21) iniciado pelo Broadcast com sucesso!");

                    new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(){
                        @Override
                        public void run(){
                            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                            Log.i(Tag, "Serviço funcionando a cada 10 segundos mesmo após reiniciar: " + c.getTime());
                        }
                    },0,10000);
                }
            });

            locationThread.start();

            return true;
        }
```

---

**E finalmente o MainActivity.java**

```java
    public void desligarServico() {
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler)this.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE );
                jobScheduler.cancelAll();
                Log.d(Tag, "Serviço parado (API>=21) com sucesso");
            }
    }
```

Não sei se é a **Thread** que fica viva mesmo após cancelar o **JobScheduler**. Tanto que acabei tentando colocar **locationThread.interrupt()**; dentro do metodo **onStopJob()**, mas ainda sem sucesso.

Já tentei colocar no metodo ***onStopJob*** da classe **JobService** o metodo `jobFinished(jobParameters, false);`. Mas ainda assim eu não consegui parar o serviço por completo utilizando o botão.

Gostaria de uma sugestão de como resolver isso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Não sei se é a Thread que fica viva mesmo após cancelar o JobScheduler

Tudo indica que sim.
Não só a Thread necessita de ser parada como tem de cancelar o Timer.

Note que um JobScheduler deve ser usado para executar uma tarefa e terminar.
Não é algo para ficar rodando à espera que seja finalizado externamente.

Caso seja usada uma Thread, ao terminar, ela deve chamar o método `jobFinished()` para indicar que o JobScheduler pode libertar o seu *wakelock* e terminar.

Se quer que a tarefa seja executada de tempos a tempos, configure o JobScheduler como periódico.